# iTunes Connect game update with grouped leaderboards and achievements

Tags: app-store-connect, game-center

I've just uploaded a new universal HD version of my iOS game that has leaderboards and achievements that are grouped with the iPhone only version.

What we see is that in the new page for the updated version there is only a reference link to the id (bundle) that identifies the leaderbords and achievements group (we click and see all the leaderboards and achievements in a popoup), but the list is empty while in the live version the list is filled. This makes sense to us since the leaderboards and achievements are shared between two games and can be changed or updated in the game center section, but we are not sure if the updated version will inherit the leaderboards and achievements. Is there anyone that had the same problem ?